# How to overload the + operator (friendly) so that you can add the value of an array element to the fields of a class object?

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading

I have a class. There are 2 fields in this class.
I have an integer array. My task is to overload the friendly "+" operator so that it is possible to add the field values ​​from the array with the value of the array elements.

For example:

```
class Test {
public:
    double x, y;
    Test() {
       x = 0;
       y = 0;
    }
};

int main() {
    Test a;
    int arr[2] { 1, 2 };
    a = arr[0] + a;
    a.Show();

    return 0;
}
```

I expect the following values:

```
x = 1;
y = 1.
```

How can I overload the + operator to complete this task? I have no thoughts at all about this.

Class Interface Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
class Pyramid {
public:
    double x, h, a; 
    Pyramid() {
        x = h = a = 3;
    }
    Pyramid(double p, double k, double q) {
        x = p;
        h = k;
        a = q;
    }
    Pyramid(const Pyramid& obj) {
        this->x = obj.x;
        this->h = obj.h;
        this->a = obj.a;
    }
    Pyramid& operator=(Pyramid& obj) {
        if (this != &obj) {
            this->x = obj.x;
            this->h = obj.h;
            this->a = obj.a;
        }
        return *this;
    }
    Pyramid operator+(const Pyramid& b) {
        Pyramid temp;
        temp.x = this->x + b.x;
        temp.h = this->h + b.h;
        temp.a = this->a + b.a;
        return temp;
    }
    Pyramid& operator*(int chislo) {
        this->x *= chislo;
        this->h *= chislo;
        this->a *= chislo;
        return *this;
    }
    Pyramid& operator++(int value) {
        this->x++;
        this->h++;
        this->a++;
        return *this;
    }
    ~Pyramid() {
    }
private:
    double Sb = 10;
};


int main() {
    setlocale(0, "");

    int arr[]{ 1,2,3,4,5 };
    Pyramid p2;
    p2 = arr[3] + p2;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is no difference between ints that are array elements and those that aren't, so a simpler and equivalent example would be  `a = 1 + a;`.

Comment: Arrays are completely immaterial here. You want to overload the addition of `int` to your class. Whether this `int` comes from some array, or from some function, or from some pointers, is utterly irrelevant, as far as overloading goes. Focus your attention on overloading the `operator+` between an `int` and your class. There is absolutely nothing fundamentally different between this overload, and any other overload, so if you already know how to overload some operators, you should be able to implement this yourself, you already know everything you need to know.

Comment: "Add the field values ​​**from the array** with the **value of the array** elements" contradicts `arr[0] + a`

Answer (score 2):

Non-class operators + can look like

```
Test operator +( const Test &t, double value )
{
    return { t.x + value, t.y + value };
}

Test operator +( double value, const Test &t )
{
    return { t.x + value, t.y + value };
}
```

Provided that either class `Test` is an aggregate or has a constructor `Test( double, double )`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to implement `a = a + arr`. Otherwise the array in the example is meaningless. *Overload the friendly "+" operator so that it is possible to add the values ​​from the array to the field values of the class.*

```
Test operator+ (const Test& t, const int* values) {
  return { t.x + values[0], t.y + value[1] };
}
```

Or

```
Test operator+ (const Test& t, const int (&values)[2]) {
  return { t.x + values[0], t.y + value[1] };
}
```

Comment: To be honest, it’s not very clear yet. I tried to add the overload you proposed to my class - nothing worked. I edited the question. Added a class interface. Is the problem that I am doing something wrong? Or your overload will not work in my class, because for this you need to finish something?

Comment: If you really need this `p2 = 4 + p2;`, @VladfromMoscow already answered your question. The array in the question is confusing.